# How to find generic property name of class instance and how to assign value to the property run time

Tags: c#, .net, class, generics, reflection

I have following classes. In instance of BE (let's say objBE) i want to select property name on run time and assign it's value. e.g. we have a combo with all properties populated, and have text box and command button on window form. I want to select property name from the combo and type some value in text box and on button click i want to find the property name from the objBE and assign the text box value to the selected property.  Couldn't get way how to get it done. Can some help.
Thanks in Advance.
H N

```
public class MyPropertyBase
{
    public int StartOffset { get; set; }
    public int EndOffset { get; set; }
}

public class MyProperty<T> : MyPropertyBase
{
    public MyProperty(T propertyValue)
    {
        PropertyValue = propertyValue;
    }

    public T PropertyValue { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator MyProperty<T>(T t)
    {
        return new MyProperty<T>(t);
    }
}

public class BE
{
    private List<Admin_Fee> _Admin_Fee = new List<Admin_Fee>();

    public MyProperty<int> RFID
    {get;set;}
    public MyProperty<string> CUSIP
    {get;set;}
    public MyProperty<string> FUND_CITY 
    {get;set;}

    public MyProperty<int> SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
    //public List<MyPropertyBase> MyDataPoints { get; set; }
    public List<Admin_Fee> Admin_Fee 
     {
         get{return _Admin_Fee;}
         set{}
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GetProperty` on the `Type`, then use `SetValue` on the `PropertyInfo` instance. Based on your description, I think you want something like this:

```
void Main()
{
    BE be  = new BE();
    SetMyPropertyValue("RFID", be, 2);
    SetMyPropertyValue("CUSIP", be, "hello, world");

    Console.WriteLine(be.RFID.PropertyValue);
    Console.WriteLine(be.CUSIP.PropertyValue);
}

private void SetMyPropertyValue(string propertyName, object instance, object valueToSet) 
{
    Type be = instance.GetType();
    Type valueType = valueToSet.GetType();
    Type typeToSet = typeof(MyProperty<>).MakeGenericType(valueType);
    object value = Activator.CreateInstance(typeToSet,valueToSet);

    var prop = be.GetProperty(propertyName);
    prop.SetValue(instance, value, null);
}
```

Comment: I was trying to assign value as you suggested                                                string strproname = "FUND_CITY";
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo proInfo =objBe.GetType().GetProperty(strproname);
MyProperty<string> propVal =new MyProperty<string>("Mark");
            proInfo.SetValue(objBe, propVal, null);  But in run time we not be be to create of propVal as we would not be able to type value in run time.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I tried to implement the code but i am get null exception      var prop =  be.GetProperty(propertyName).

Comment: The suggestion looks great. Look like it will work for me. Thanks a lot. But some more enhancement would be required. We would be able set value set as be.rfid=2, we also want to set  Be.rfid.startoffset=1500 and be.RFID.EndOffset=1502. And also if type is collection like Public List<Admin_Fee> Admin_Fee,then we would also be required to set value for each property of <Admin_Fee> type.

Comment: I have accepted the answers. Sorry i missed to accept the helping answers.